# Reduce Macbook data usage while it is connected to internet through iphone hotspot

Tags: network, data-transfer, tethering

Is there a way to limit internet data usage while a Mac laptop is connected to internet through an iPhone hotspot? Some background tasks such as backing up, dropbox activity, automatic updates, can be using a large amount of data. Obviously it is possible to prevent some traffic by manually disabling some programs (e.g. Dropbox) but is there a more automated way of doing it?

Comment: Have you checked "low data mode?"

Comment: @SteveChambers I was not aware of this option on MacOS. I have just enabled it and will monitor if it helps. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [TripMode](https://tripmode.ch/).

You can block applications on a per-network basis.