How can I stop Dropbox syncing when tethering to a mobile hotspot? (Mac desktop)
I travel frequently and since most of the time phone tethering is not unlimited, I don't want Dropbox to sync over a hotspot.
It seems that Dropbox has no functionality to detect this and stop syncing (on the Mac desktop client).
How can I make sure Dropbox doesn't suck up my bandwidth when I'm on a hotspot?  "Just remember to pause it when hotspot connects" is error-prone because it relies on remembering, and if I forget, I could lose a lot of the monthly data on my cell plan. I just want to automate this.

Does this answer your question?  https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/454149/89967

@MarcWilson I'll check it out, thanks for the pointer.

I'm working around this with the Bartender app, which can hide Mac status bar items using logic you specify.
I show the Dropbox icon only when I'm connected to my Hotspot, and Dropbox is not paused.  That way it comes to my attention immediately - I notice the Dropbox status bar icon because it's usually hidden.  That's my trigger to click pause.
Here's what it looks like (just substitute your network name):

This seems like an obvious oversight from Dropbox and it's very disappointing that there's no native solution, but this seems reliable (if a bit manual) for now.
I tried a few solutions with Keyboard Maestro and scripting as well but did not get those working.
(I've found Bartender useful for several other things, like showing Battery icon only if running on battery power, and showing Wifi icon only if I'm not connected.)
